# Unlinking and saving materials as a copy from .blend file

Tags: blender, fbx

When we export .fbx file from blender and import them in unity, we get the object without textures and materials. I figured out to get the texture by *selecting the image in UV/Image editor sreen and save it as a copy in Image Option.*

**But I couldn't find any way to *save as* or *copy* materials (already attached with object in blender) so that I could attach material to model/game object manually in unity3D.**

I have gone through many toturials like baking textures etc. but nothing was helpful. **Please note that I do not have to apply Material to model in blender, instead I want the copy of material that are already attached with object, came with .blend file got from internet source.**

Tutorial link and explanation will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [link](http://www.edy.es/dev/docs/materials-and-textures-from-blender-to-unity-3d/)
There you get the Information, that only the diffuse color can be exported. Thats more than i expected. Why?
Blender-materials are different than textures. There is no Dataformat for Blender-materials as you have them with textures or objects.
Blender-materials are bound to the internal Data and an full-export seems really hard. Look at blenders Outliner panel and change the view from "All Scenes" to "Datablocks". There you can see how many aspects could be exported. All those would be needed for a full-import on a different program. That is much work, which has not been done so far (as i know).